# Is it possible to make the device filesystem name , /dev/sd?1 , stay constant every time we reconnect the SanDisk USB Cruzer drive?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, udev, devices

Is it possible to make the device filesystem name , /dev/sdi1 , shown by `lsblk -f` stay constant every time we disconnect and reconnect the SanDisk USB Cruzer drive? I am running Ubuntu Linux 16.04 on an Lenovo Thinkstation desktop computer.

I believe the SanDisk USB Cruzer drive automatically mounts on insertion.

If it is possible, what are the steps necessary to make this possible?

Comment: Most applications dont care what `/dev/sd?` is used, as it can always be found (eg `findmnt`) if you use a disc LABEL or UUID for example. Can you say why you need to fix the device?

Comment: @meuh, Thank you for your comment.  Currently we are looking at how to make usb device filename persist across reboots or unplugging and replugging in the usb for Ubuntu Linux 16.04.

     When I keep plugging them in and pulling them out from the USB ports and they keep getting names like /dev/sdg1 or /dev/sdi1 . However, the device names are not persistent — whether the BusPirate pops up as /dev/sdg1 or /dev/sdi1 depends on the order in which are the devices discovered by the kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to specify the mounting point based on the device's UUID.

You should refer to the [official Ubuntu documentation page on the subject](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID) for usage details.

Here are examples (your output will be different, but similarly formatted). The command:

```
sudo blkid
```

produces an output similar to:

```
/dev/sda1: TYPE="ntfs" UUID="72C0DE8EC0DE57C5" LABEL="windows" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="30fcb748-ad1e-4228-af2f-951e8e7b56df" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: TYPE="swap" UUID="8c4e69f8-5074-42c0-8134-0b2429c4c02c" 
/dev/sdb1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="4848-E35A" TYPE="vfat"
```

you would then have to change the entry in `fstab` from:

```
/dev/sda2 /mnt/Mint ext4 defaults 0 0
```

to something like:

```
UUID=30fcb748-ad1e-4228-af2f-951e8e7b56df /mnt/Mint ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. Thank you for your comment. Currently we are looking at how to make usb device filename persist across reboots or unplugging and replugging in the usb for Ubuntu Linux 16.04. When I keep plugging them in and pulling them out from the USB ports and they keep getting names like /dev/sdg1 or /dev/sdi1 . However, the device names are not persistent  because it  depends on the order in which are the devices discovered by the kernel.  May I ask why does specifying the mounting point based on the USB device's UUID solve  our requirement?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point.

Comment: @Fergus-Incoronato: Nice edit!

Comment: I enjoyed reading your answer. If I change your fstab example to: /dev/usbhd1 /mnt/Mint ext4 defaults 0 0 where /dev/usbhd1 is Serge's symbolic link, what should the lsblk -f output look like? My architect manager would like to find out what the significance of your nice answer is on preserving mount points across  reboots and USB reinsertions?

Comment: @Frank:  `lsblk -f`'s output is not affected by mounts.  What will change is the actual device associated (/dev/sda2) but the UUID will always match that actual USB key. (with the only exception would be if you would have cloned the key.)

Comment: Thanks for the great comment. What does it mean to clone the USB key? I thought lsblk -f shows the mount point, What Ubuntu Linux command should our architect and I use to test if the *mount point has been preserved in between reboots and USB disconnects?

Comment: There are ways to do an exact copy of certain media that will copy its serial number as well.  I was only mentioning that possibility, not recommending it.

Comment: How do we make a udev rule and fstab rule which differentiates between 2 identical SanDisk Cruzer 8GB USB drives I purchased from Best Buy? Thank you.

Comment: With the UUID as described in detail in my answer and Fergus' update.

Comment: The device name will change but not the UUID.

Comment: There is actually one more way to refer to devices by UUID on most systems: `/dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID`

Comment: I read in Evi Nemeth's Unix and Linux System Administration Handbook , 4th Edition, Page 715, that "when you list the contents of an automounted filesystem's parent directory , the directory appears empty and you cannot browse the automounts in a GUI filesystem browser such as Nautilus and that the photos filesystem is automounted under /portal . It's accessible through its' full pathname". But, that is not why I observe. Instead when I cd to /portal/photos the kernel says "no such filename or directory" Furthermore , I cannot login to my home directory. How do I fix this?

Comment: How is that even remotely related to your home directory or to the mounting point.  You asked a fairly intelligent question but then you didn't follow the answer given and you're jumping to irrelevant stuff.  Focus.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and criticism. I sincerely accept it . When I use a udev rule ACTION=="add" and RUN+="/bin/ln -sf  /media/autousb/%k /media/frank/usb/%k" , the udev or autofs service creates the directory /media/autousb with 755 permission rather than 777 permission so that udev or autofs cannot create files inside /media/autousb. May I ask how to fix this?

Comment: I moved to Seattle, Washington a month ago. Is there a way when Docker is stopped and restarted to prevent the use case where Docker is stopped and the original USB mount point is not discarded and lingers on.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am almost sure it's not possible to assign the # of sd, but you might work this around with `udev` rule that would set up links to the actual sdX and sdXY upon disk drive connection:

> KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{model}=="USB 2.0 Storage
>   Device", SYMLINK+="usbhd%n"

would create these links:

- /dev/usbhd - The fdiskable node
- /dev/usbhd1 - The first partition (mountable)
- /dev/usbhd2 - The second partition (mountable)

[Source](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#example-usbhdd)

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. Once I create your rule using sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules, how do I make sure the 3 links you mentioned in your answer get created properly? What should I do after: sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart?

Comment: Just reconnect the device. Alternatively, use `udevadm trigger` command (see `man udevadm`)

Comment: Please note, that you might have to change the model string in the rule. Also you could use serial no of the device to match. See `udev` docs for details and samples

Comment: Thank you for your 2 great comments. I just followed your recommendation to just reconnect the USB device and I can now see the links /dev/usbhd  and /dev/usbhd1. Could I ask why it's not possible to assign the # of the sd?

Comment: @Fergus-Incoronato, Nice edit of Julie Pelletier's answer. How do I use Serge's answer with /etc/fstab? Thank you very much.

Comment: because the number is assigned internally by the `scsi subsystem` and it picks the first available.

Comment: if you like to set it in fstab then do it as always:  `/dev/usbhd1 /path/to/mount/point fstype defaults 1 2`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Suppose I run sudo mount -a after setting /etc/fstab to /dev/usbhd1 /path/to/mount/point fstype defaults 1 2. What steps should our architect and I do next after a SanDisk USB disconnect?

Comment: If you are going to connect and disconnect your HD regularly,then set up `udev` rule to mount it upon insertion at expected location. you could omit fstab entry in this case

Comment: Thank you for your expertise. How do I set up a udev rule to mount the HD upon insertion so as to eliminate an fstab entry? Would this udev rule apply to reboots also?

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials on udev configuration available online.

Comment: Please recommend the best online udev configuration tutorial you are familiar with. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of finding the `/dev/sd` device that corresponds to a disc that has no LABEL nor UUID is to use its serial id. For example, my SSD says

```
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda
    Model Number:       KINGSTON SH103S3240G                    
    Serial Number:      50999B9999926F99
```

And I can find which `/dev/sd` device it is by following the link in `/dev/disk/by-id/` using the serial id built from this information. Eg

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/ata-KINGSTON_SH103S3240G_50999B9999926F99
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Apr 28 17:22 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-KINGSTON_SH103S3240G_50999B9999926F99 -> ../../sda
```

Usually, we set a UUID on a partition then we can find the device simply with `findmnt`. Eg

```
$ findmnt -n -o source UUID=e7522030-f6e3-472d-8013-3a3316fd15a3
/dev/sda3
```

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer and comment. Here is my udev rule using your serial id  suggestion: SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",ATTRS{serial}=="4C530001041030118021",KERNEL=="sd*",
SYMLINK+="usbhd%n". After I restart the udev service using sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart I still cannot find the links /dev/usbhd , /dev/usbhd1 or/dev/usbhd2. May I ask what steps I forgot to do or what mistakes I made?

Comment: Did you unplug/replug the device? You might want to add `ACTION=="add",`and put your file last in the rules (ie rename it 99-...)

Comment: @mueh, Thank you for your comment. Do I need to unplug and replug the device after I add ACTION=="add" to the udev rule?

Comment: I see from the other answer you have created the links ok. The `ACTION=="add",` is for the future, to only create the links when the device is plugged in (added). I'm not sure if you need to create another rule to remove the link when you unplug the device (`ACTION=="remove",`).

Comment: Thank you for your comments and answer today. Why does not the  /dev/usbhd1 , the symbolic link to the first partition, show up in the lsblk -f output? What happens if change the mount point from /home/frank/data1 to /home/frank/data59 corresponding to the symbolic link /dev/usbhd1?

Comment: When you mount the device, the symbolic link is followed to get to the real device `/dev/sd..`, and this is used for the mount. So the OS no longer knows about the symbolic-link name at a later time.

Comment: Good morning. How do I set up a udev rule to mount the SanDisk Cruzer USB upon insertion so as to eliminate an fstab entry? I would like this udev rule to apply to reboots also? Thank you.

Comment: Post a new question.

Comment: Could you please take a look at this new question I just posted, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285624/how-do-i-set-up-a-udev-rule-to-mount-the-sandisk-cruzer-usb-upon-insertion-in-or? Thank you.

Comment: Could I ask if  there is a way when Docker is stopped and restarted to prevent the use case where Docker is stopped and the, docker unmount lingers on. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I dont use Docker. You should post a new question.